# Remove .val after certain amount of time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using a function to add a 'Thank you' message to a newsletter signup on success.

```
$('#subForm').animate({opacity : 1}, 300);
      } else {
        $('#subForm input[type="text"]').val('Thank you');
        $('#subForm').animate({opacity : 1}, 300);
      }
});
```

What I am trying to work out is how to remove the 'Thank you' value after a few seconds.

Comment: Please check your code. You cannot use `else` without `if`.

Comment: Why are you showing a "Thank you" message in an _input_? (Can the user type in that input?)

Comment: @VisioN:The code isn't the whole function - just the relevant part for my question.

Comment: @nnnnnn The Thank You shows up once the email has been submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#subForm input[type='text']").val("");
}, 1000);
```

The second argument stands for number of milliseconds of the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout

```
setTimeout("$('#subForm input[type=\"text\"]').val('');", 2000);
```